# jQuery: manually close dialog

Tags: jquery, dialog

I'm having my own listview widget inside a jQuery dialog.  I'd like having the following dialog attributes for the dialog:

- close on esc
- but don't autoclose the dialog when clicking somewhere

I set `beforeclose: function(){return false;}`
which disables auto-close

The problems are:

- Closing by esc doesnt work anymore;
- When clicking my listview, I'm trying to close the dialog manually by using `this.div.dialog({beforeclose:null});` but this doesn't help.

So i can't close the dialog at all. :/

Any ideas to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

beforeclose sounds like callback that calls a function before the dialog closes. You need to look for a click event or the element that the click event is attached to and try and stop this.